# TailwindCSS is not changing the text colour correctly

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS with my Laravel and Vue project.
The problem I am having is when I do

```
                <h4 class="font-medium text-orange-500">
                    {{ movie.title }}
                </h4>
```

The actual result is a black text.
When I do

```
                    <h4 class="font-medium text-white">
                    {{ status.title }}
                </h4>
```

The text is white and it works.
So, the text can be changed to white but other than white color all appears as black. How can I fix this? To be honest, I have no idea where to look in the project to fix this issue.
To use TailwindCSS, I am using Laravel Breeze.

Comment: You could just use the Tailwind documentation for [Text Color](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color). `text-orange-500` doesn't exist. Either `text-red-500` or `text-yellow-500`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not looking at the documentation properly. I thought I can do -500 for all colors.

Answer (score 0):

Orange is not one of the colors that's enabled out of the box in Tailwind. There is a palette for orange though, you just have to include it.

```
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        orange: colors.orange,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference